Warning "Substitution replacement not terminated", only in sourced shell script
I'm trying to remove all directories whose path matches a certain pattern from the path, within a script that would be sourced using .. The script prints a warning "Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1." when sourced:
Edit: including full script.  Note that there are multiple errors here!
vv=`echo $0 | perl -ne 's/([0-9]+)/ and print $1'`
node_home=`ls -d /opt/node$xx* | head -1`
PATH=`perl -e 'print join q{:},grep !m{/node-},split(m{[:]},$ENV{"PATH"})'`
PATH=$node_home/bin:$PATH

But the warning doesn't appear when I enter the first PATH= line into bash interactively.

Are you sure this is exactly the line causing problems? I can source it without errors.

That is a compiler error (fatal) that comes from using the s/// operator with one delimiter missing. E.g. if using s// or s{}. Since you have none of those in that line, it seems likely the problem comes from somewhere else.

The error actually comes from the first line of the script. I meant to do a pattern-match, m//, not a substitution, s///.
But that line actually doesn't do what I wanted anyway.  I wanted to install the script in a certain directory under several linked names, e.g.
node16vars
node18vars
node20vars

but $0 inside a sourced script is actually the name of the shell, e.g. -bash.  Since my shell is bash, I can instead use the line
node_major_version=`echo $BASH_SOURCE | perl -ne 'm/([0-9]+)/ and print $1'`

to pull the first number out of the as-installed script name.
